# How to implement Borrow<T> when T wraps borrowed data?

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

Given the following definitions from [How to borrow a field for serialization but create it during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733047/how-to-borrow-a-field-for-serialization-but-create-it-during-deserialization):

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct SerializeThing<'a> {
    small_header: (u64, u64, u64),
    big_body: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct DeserializeThing {
    small_header: (u64, u64, u64),
    big_body: String,
}
```

How do I implement the `Borrow` trait so as to store the owned data naturally in (e.g.) HashMaps and query them by either them or by their borrowed counterparts? The closest thing that appears possible is as follows:

```
impl DeserializeThing {
    fn as_serialize(&self) -> SerializeThing<'_> {
        let DeserializeThing { small_header, big_body } = self;
        let small_header = *small_header;
        let big_body = big_body.as_str();
        SerializeThing { small_header, big_body }
    }
}
```

which is not quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

`Borrow::borrow` must return a reference, and there is no way you can get a reference to a `SerializeThing` from a reference to a `DeserializeThing` as these types are simply not ABI compatible.

---

If performance is important and you can't pay for the construction of `DeserializeThing` instances/allocation of strings, then you could use `hashbrown::HashMap` instead of `std::collections::HashMap`.

`hashbrown` is the library that the standard library uses for its own `HashMap` implementation, but it has some more useful methods.

One which would be useful for you now is the [raw entry API](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/0.9.1/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry) ([and mutable raw entry](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/0.9.1/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut)).

In particular, it allows you to get a map entry from its hash and a matching function:

> ```
> pub fn from_hash<F>(self, hash: u64, is_match: F) -> Option<(&'a K, &'a > V)> where
>    F: FnMut(&K) -> bool
> ```
>
> Access an entry by hash.

Since you can implement `Hash` for both `DeserializeThing` and `SerializeThing` to get the same the hashes for the same values, this API would be simple to use in your case.